# How to specify SyncDirectionOrder by Table using SyncOrchestrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have separated the tables into a different scopes with different `SyncDirectionOrder` because I have not figured out how to do it using a single scope:

```
public void Sync()
{
    Sync("BidirectionalScope", SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload);
    Sync("UploadScope", SyncDirectionOrder.Upload);
    Sync("DownloadScope", SyncDirectionOrder.Download);
} 

protected SyncOperationStatistics Sync(string syncScope, SyncDirectionOrder syncDirectionOrder)
{
    var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(...);
    var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(...);

    var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
    {
        LocalProvider = localProvider,
        RemoteProvider = remoteProvider,
        Direction = syncDirectionOrder
    };

    return syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
}
```

Comment: Were you able to specify SyncDirectionOrder for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant, using the Syncorchestrator, the scope is the only place you can specify the sync direction.

Comment: How to specify sync direction in scope. Can you share an example or point to any such reference?

Comment: Looking for way to configure sync direction for each table.

Comment: as above, you cant specify sync direction per table. if you want to go that route, create a scope for each table